# how to fix the unicode problem on configparser

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I use Python 3.7 and
configparser 3.7.4.

I have a rank.ini:

```
[example]
placeholder : \U0001F882
```

And i have a main.py file:

```py
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('ranks.ini')

print('')
test = '\U0001F882'
print(type(test))
print(test)
test2 = config.get('example', 'placeholder')
print(type(test2))
print(test2)
```

The result of the code is:

```
<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
\U0001F882
```

Why is the var test2 not "" and how i can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this one out since python3 sees everything as unicode explained [here](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

If my understanding is correct the original print is being seen like this `u'\U0001F882'`, so it converts it into the character.

However, when you pass the variable in using the configparser as a string the unicode escape character is essentially getting lost such as `'\\U0001F882'`.

You can see this difference if you print test and test2's repr

```
print(repr(test))
print(repr(test2))
```

To get the output you want you will have to unicode escape the string value

```
print(test2.encode('utf8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

Hope this works for you.